# WordPress и генерация копий изображений

Tags: wordpress, seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Тема WP генерирует копии изображений. Мне интересно, что из этих копий попадает в индекс ПС (например в Яндекс.картинки)? Только оригинал изображения? Или копии тоже попадут в индекс?

Comment: Яндекс и любой другой поисковик не умеют залезать на сервер и смотреть, какие там картинки лежат. Они видят только то, что на странице. Если на странице выведена картинка 150x150, то она и попадет в индекс.

Comment: @KAGG Design, на самом деле я вывожу картинку 150х150, но в яндекс картинках я нахожу её в оригинальном размере 1500х1500 с ссылкой на мой сайт.

Comment: На самом деле, скорей всего, там srcset, как везде в WP, и тогда исходник может попасть в ПС.